# Proof of the Quotient Rule

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

If the derivatives $f'(x_0)$ and $g'(x_0)$ exist for the functions $f, g: (x_0 - d, x_0 + d)\to\mathbb{R}$, then for $g(x_0) \neq 0$, $\frac{f}{g}$ is also differentiable in $x_0$ and the following applies:

$(\frac{f}{g})'(x_0) = \frac{f'(x_0)g(x_0) - f(x_0)g'(x_0)}{(g(x_0))^2}$

How can I prove this formula?

Comment: By writing it as a product and then apply the product rule (if that is allowed as a proof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition!

We have $$\frac{f(x+h)/g(x+h)-f(x)/g(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x+h)}{hg(x+h)g(x)}.\tag{1}$$ As $$f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x+h) = (f(x+h)-f(x))g(x)-f(x)(g(x+h)-g(x)),$$ we can rewrite the right hand side of equation (1) in the form 
\begin{multline}
\frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))g(x)-f(x)(g(x+h)-g(x))}{hg(x)g(x+h)} \\
= \frac{1}{g(x)g(x+h)}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}g(x)-f(x)\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right)
\end{multline}
Now take the limit $h\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of proving this using logarithmic differentiation:
$$
y(x) = f(x)/g(x)\\
\ln(y(x)) = \ln[f(x)/g(x)] = \ln(f(x)) - \ln(g(x))\\
\frac{1}{y(x)} y'(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}f'(x) - \frac 1{g(x)}g'(x)\\
y'(x) = \left[\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} - \frac {g'(x)}{g(x)}\right]y(x)\\
y'(x) = \left[\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} - \frac {g'(x)}{g(x)}\right]\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\\
y'(x) = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{[g(x)]^2}
$$

---

Alternatively, write $y(x) = f(x)[g(x)]^{-1}$.  Apply the product and chain rule as necessary.